# Way of removing a kivy attribute?

Tags: python, kivy

I'm using the following class template, which has the benefits of making the buttons flat, and removing the grey tint so that they appear brighter:

```
<Button>:
    background_normal: ''
```

I'd like an option to change this at runtime (revert to 'original theme', if you like), so I tried giving the class an ID, setting the property to None and doing an ask_update. I'm not even sure if changing the class should work, but I'm guessing it should... but in any case, it doesn't like being set to None.

Is there a way of removing the attribute 'background_normal' from the class? Or is there a better way of achieving what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`background_normal` is a string property which defaults to `'atlas://data/images/defaulttheme/button'`. If you set it to the string `''` it will be "deactivated". If you want to set it back you can set it to the default again.

Here is the appropriate [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.button.html)

If you simply want to change the color of the button you can also look into `background_color` which is a list property with the default `[1,1,1,1]`. If you want to change it to e.g. some red you could set it to `[2,1,1,1]`.

Comment: But how do I undo the effects of setting this to '' ?

Comment: Set it to something else again.

Comment: Sorry wait. It's not a string property, if I head read the documentation I linked I would have known that...

Comment: @zeeMonkeez You are completly right. Somehow I messed background_color and background_normal up. Thanks!